# UIImage imageNamed suffixes

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage

Is there a resource anywhere that shows different suffixes for the imageNamed function.

I know of these...

```
blah.png - normal image
blah@2x.png - retina image
```

Then I've seen this mentioned...

```
blah@2x~ipad.png - a retina image specifically for ipad.
```

Is there one for...

```
blah~ipad.png - a normal image specifically for ipad?
```

Is there a proper list of these anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Generally we are giving our own names to .png images. we have two images, one for original size and other for double size for clarity of image.

that naming convention is blah.png for 1x and blah@2x.png for double size. there is no need to write blah_ipad.png.

Comment: You can use blah~ipad.png and blah@2x~ipad.png when you want to use different resources on different devices.